# ASP.NET MVC insert data from controller / view into SQL Server database (Entity Framework database first)

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm having a problem by inserting data from view to my SQL Server database.

When I click "Create" in my view I'm getting the error message, that there would be missing a key for different tables (like Kunde/Customer and Ort/City).

Every table has a primary key and different foreign keys (1:n) defined by SQL Server Management Studio. The primary key is autogenerated by SQL Server.

The data that should be insert from view and should be saved to different tables.

Code from my model view:

```
public class ViewModelKundeController
{
    public string AnredeText { get; set; }
    public string Vorname { get; set; }
    public string Nachname { get; set; }
    public string Strasse { get; set; }
    public int Hausnummer { get; set; }
    public string Telefon { get; set; }
    public string EMail { get; set; }
    public string Aktiv { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> AGBDatum { get; set; }
    public string Anmerkung { get; set; }
    public string WhatsappAkzeptiert { get; set; }
    public string WebAkzeptiert { get; set; }
    public string AGBAkzeptiert { get; set; }
    public string Postleitzahl { get; set; }
    public string Ort { get; set; }
}
```

My data models (used for my Viewmodel) are autogenerated by Entity Framework connection (maybe there is the error?)

`DbContext` descendant class:

```
public class KundeDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<tbl_Kunde> Kunden { get; set; }
    public DbSet<tbl_Ort> Orte { get; set; }
    public DbSet<tbl_Anrede> Anrede { get; set; }
}
```

Controller code:

```
// GET: Kunde/Create
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ViewModelKundeController viewmodel)
{
    var kunde = new tbl_Kunde()
        {
            Vorname = viewmodel.Vorname,
            Nachname = viewmodel.Nachname,
            Strasse = viewmodel.Strasse,
            Hausnummer = viewmodel.Hausnummer,
            Telefon = viewmodel.Telefon,
            EMail = viewmodel.EMail,
            Aktiv = viewmodel.Aktiv,
            AGBAkzeptiert = viewmodel.AGBAkzeptiert,
            WebAkzeptiert = viewmodel.WebAkzeptiert,
            WhatsappAkzeptiert = viewmodel.WhatsappAkzeptiert,
            AGBDatum = viewmodel.AGBDatum,
            Anmerkung = viewmodel.Anmerkung
        };

    var anrede = new tbl_Anrede()
        {
            AnredeText = viewmodel.AnredeText
        };

    var orte = new tbl_Ort()
        {
            Ort = viewmodel.Ort,
            Postleitzahl = viewmodel.Postleitzahl
        };

    kdb.Kunden.Add(kunde);
    kdb.Anrede.Add(anrede);
    kdb.Orte.Add(orte);

    kdb.SaveChanges();

    return View();
}
```

Comment: Post `tbl_Kunde` class please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Every table has a primary key and different foreign keys (1:n)

It looks like foreign keys are not nullable and it means that you have to provide values for the keys. You can read [Creating and modifying relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/relationships#creating-and-modifying-relationships) to have a basic understanding.

In your case if `tbl_Kunde` has a foreign key to `tbl_Ort` it may look like this:

```
var orte = new tbl_Ort()
{
    Ort = viewmodel.Ort,
    Postleitzahl = viewmodel.Postleitzahl
};

var kunde = new tbl_Kunde()
{
    Vorname = viewmodel.Vorname,
    ...
    Orte = orte 
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Albert! I think my problem is, that i want to insert data in different tables from one view. For example i want to insert postal code and city to table/model Ort (primary key ort/cityID) and link the cityID to the customer table with the column cityID, so that i know to which city and postal code the customer belongs. Any idea?

Comment: @Daniel3011, It is possible if you have navigation properties (i.e. `tbl_Kunde.Orte`). Navigation props work along with foreign key props and `EF` will produce `sql` that will provide values for foreign keys within one `SaveChanges`. Without nav props (having only foreign key props (cityId)) you have to provide values manually using more than one `SaveChanges`

Comment: So i have to create for every table (autocreated as model by EF) another modelclass which contains attributes like [KEY] and [FOREIGN KEY]?

Comment: No. That should be autocreated by EF for example in `tbl_Kunde`.